# How do I put in two variables in a matlab function (ERROR: inner matrix dimensions must agree)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, user-defined-functions

When I try to plot a function `h` in MATLAB, using a variable `omega` which is defined as its own function, I get an `Inner matrix dimensions must agree, error using _*_` response from the console.

The function works when I use a `+` between the seperate function-components of `h`; It does not work when I try multiplying the two inner functions in `h`, which is, from what I guess, what causes the matrix dim error.

```
    function h = freqp(omega)

    k = (1:1024-1);
    hh = (1:1024-1);
    omega = zeros(length(k),1);
    omega = (k-1)*((2*pi)/1024);

    hh = 2*exp((-3j)*omega)*cos(omega); % This works for ...omega) + cos(...
                                        % but not for ...omega) * cos(, why?
    y = fft(hh);
    stem(real(y), omega);
```

How can I solve this? I read the info on mathworks but it only gives a solution for e.g. loading a file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since Omega is a vector, the addition works. But multiplication of two vectors will result as a matrix. You can modify

> ```
>                  hh = 2*exp((-3j)*omega)*cos(omega);
> ```
>
> as
>
> ```
>                  hh = 2*exp((-3j)*omega)*(cos(omega))';
> ```

or looking for element wise multiplication,
use

> ```
>                  hh = 2*exp((-3j)*omega).*cos(omega);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The part `exp((-3j)*omega` worked fine because `-3j` is a complex scalar and `omega` a vector. Thus, MATLAB multiplies each element of `omega` with -3i. However, that result is a vector itself. Also `cos(omega)` is a vector, and both are row vectors.

In this case, with two vectors, the `*`-operator means dot product but that would be calculated between a column vector and a row vector, not two row vectors. So, `[1 2 3] * [4 5 6]` will raise the same error you are reporting, but `[1 2 3] * [4 5 6]'` yields 32.

From invoking `fft` on `hh` your code looks, however, as if you never intended to calculate a dot product (a scalar) but instead were looking for element-wise multiplication. The operator for element-wise multiplication is `.*`, such that your expression would be instead

```
hh = 2*exp((-3j)*omega).*cos(omega);
```